# node.js :one route call every time

Tags: node.js, express, routes, sails.js

I have two routes in sails.js application like this

```
'POST /subscribe',

'GET /:category'
```

Problem is `/:category` route always run for every other routes execution

Comment: I don't know much about sails, but I believe as for basic precedence rules you should place your `GET/:category` route first.

Comment: which rule i need to place first

Comment: This route`GET/:category`

Comment: It means top of the route??

Comment: Yes, declare `GET /:category` first

Comment: When calling `/subscribe`,  are you calling with POST method ?

Comment: Yes i will call with POST

Comment: And when you request `/subscribe` with POST method, it is handled by `GET /:category` ?

Comment: nop the two routes are entirely different

Comment: You only have these two routes ? If yes, then it is totally normal that every GET request will go through `GET /:category`

Comment: I found a solution, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Updating due to comments.

3 ways to create different endpoints per category.

1. Define all endpoints ahead of time.

   /category/arts

   /category/electronics

   /category/anything_else_you_want
2. Make an endpoint /category/:category which handles the :category part of the url to determine category and what action to take.

   /category/:category
3. Parse the url query string to get the requested category.

   /category

But then in your endpoint do something like the following.

```
var params = req.params
var category = params.category
```

How you would access each of the above 3 from the client (browser)

1. http://www.something.com/category/arts
2. http://www.something.com/category/arts
3. http://www.something.com/category?category="arts"

By doing /:category, that endpoint would match other routes for example www.something.com/login, or www.something.com/admin...you get the point.

Let me know if that all makes sense.

Comment: But actually i want to list as `/:category`

Comment: Actually i want routes like this  `/electronics` ,`/arts`

Comment: Then you need to specify them ahead of time.  I'll modify my post.

Comment: No.  You have two choice to accomplish what you want to do.  1.  Do what I mentioned above.  Have it be /category/some_category.  2.  When you start your server create separate endpoints for each category.  For example, /arts, /electronics, /anything_else you want.  But you will have to define them without the : in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not a sails user, but I setup a quick project to test. And I found an answer, you have to explicitly set the method to your `/:category` route this way :

```
'get /:category': {
    view: 'homepage'
},
'post /subscribe': {
    view: 'sub'
}
```

And if you wish to add another get route, add it before `/:category` this way :

```
'get /another-route': {
    view: 'someotherview'
},
'get /:category': {
    view: 'homepage'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a sails app, and I use a route like that:

```
'GET /:userName': 'MainController.showDashboard',
```

or something like that. I have to be careful with this route, because it matches every route (every GET with a single `/`). For example, if I want a contact page to be located at `myurl.com/contact`, I have to declare that route *before* the `/:userName` wildcard route:

```
'GET /contact': 'MainController.showContactPage',
'GET /:userName': 'MainController.showDashboard',
```

If I put them the other way around, then the url `myurl.com/contact` would be intercepted by the userName route, and route to the `showDashboard` method with `'contact'` interpreted as a userName. With the ordering as above, `/contact` is detected properly and sent to the right controller.

---

The bottom line is that routes are checked for matching in the same order they appear in your `routes.js` file (no matter what form of declaration you use), so if you have a catch-all (like `/:category`), you should put it last.